# having trouble in saving form data into ManyToMany field

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

My Model is like

```
class Dish(models.Model):
    names = models.ManyToManyField(DishName)
    restaurant = models.ManyToManyField(Restaurant)
```

And My view file is like

```
  def AddDish(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            dishname = request.POST.get('name')
            res = request.POST.get('restaurant')
            restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(id=res)


            r = Dish(generic_name=GenericName,
                       names=dishname,
                       restaurant=restaurant,
                           )
            r.save()
```

And when I try to add my values to Dish model this error occue

**Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use restaurant.set() instead.**

I tried to use  set  but Didnt get where to use this like I tried  `restaurant.set(r)`   but no luck till now . Any help would be highly appreciated . thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def AddDish(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        dishname = request.POST.get('name')
        res = request.POST.get('restaurant')
        restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(id=res)
        dn = DishName(name=dishname)
        r = Dish.objects.create()
        r.restaurant.add(restaurant)
        r.names.add(dn)
```

I'm however *not* convinced that you here should use a `ManyToManyField` in the first place. If a dish only belongs to *one* `Restaurant`, then you probably should use a `ForeignKey`.

You thu first need to *save* your `Dish` *before* you can alter the `ManyToMany` relations, since otherwise, your `Dish` has no primary key assigned to it.

Comment: thanks for answer Willem . Actually its been designed already. According to my understanding now we will add a restaurant first ? which is not good,

Comment: @gamer: but the `restaurant` in your original code *was* already saved, since with a `get` you aim to retrieve it? The point is that both the objects where you want to add a relation to should exists first.

Comment: Thanks for reply . Both restaurant and dish name table exist with all entries into it . Like I have two tables and there are entries of restaurants and dishname . First I have retrieved and showed into template of AddDish where user select both of them from drop down and submit . And onSubmit this view works. So In this case I dont need to create a new restaurant and dishName

Comment: @gamer: no, indeed, in that case you can simply fetch these both from the database. You furthermore might want to consider using model forms: this can do the boilerplate logic for you https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: MainApp_dish.dish_category_id    . I am getting this error Now

Comment: @gamer: that is likely because your `Dish` has a `ForeignKey` named `category`, and you need to fill in a reference to a proper category.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `.set` ==>

```
def AddDish(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        dishname = request.POST.get('name')
        res_id = request.POST.get('restaurant')
        restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(id=res_id)
        dn = DishName.objects.get(name=dishname)
        dish = Dish.objects.create(generic_name=GenericName)
        dish.names.set([dn])
        dish.restaurant.set([restaurant])
        dish.save()
```